# JWT Token Security NextJS vs React

Tags: reactjs, security, next.js, single-page-application, next-auth

I am working on a project where we use NextJS instead of React because my architect thinks storing the JWT token on the client side is not secure. We are not using SSR. The Backend is Spring.

When using a react application I know that if storing the token in local/session storage we are vulnerable to XSS attack and if it's stored in an HTTP-only cookie we are vulnerable to CSRF.

In NextJS we are using NextAuth. The token is executed only from the server (server-side component) and it's not saved in the browser. To get the token we have a NextJS session. However, is there no possibility to steal the session? I think the session ID is stored in the cookie. In my opinion, when having a SPA there is always a risk, because it's running in the browser. Is NextJS a better choice for this setup and does it solve this security problem?

Comment: Authentication scheme is (almost) independent of the framework you use (though some frameworks prefer one or another). You can do React with plain old sessions or structured tokens (jwt), and I don't know NextJS, but that's probably the case there too. In the end, whatever framework or client you use (oldschool web, SPA, etc.) there will be some kind of a session identifier _somewhere_ on the client as it needs to maintain a session. In short, a plain old session is more secure than structured tokens and should be used unless tokens are necessary. This can be done in ~any framework.